# Unable to start a service on computer '.'

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have the start and stop service code

Start:

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController("MyService");
service.Start();
var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5); // 5seconds
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
btnTxt = "Stop Service";
```

Stop:

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController("MyService");
service.Stop();
var timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5); // 5seconds
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
btnTxt = "Start Service";
```

When i was using this code in my Windows Form Application directly and running the visula studio as administrator it was working fine.
But now i have created a class library and calling the method from the class library in Form. cs file. So now it gives the exception that "Cannot start the service Myservice on computer '.'. Can anyone help what could be the possible problem??
All the other methods in the class library are working fine otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

A service will not have permission to "interact with the desktop" and Form.cs will be referencing libraries that require this privilege, so the service will fail to start.

Currently there is a very useful solution available [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/09/23/c-windows-services-1-of-2-creating-a-debuggable-windows.aspx) and [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/10/07/c-windows-services-2-of-2-self-installing-windows-service-template.aspx) that will run your service as a console app in the debugger or as "proper" service otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to at least do some log:

Can you add a try catch for take exception

```
try{

// your code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

and paste here ex.message